# How did Bran get over the wall?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

I've read how Gilly and Sam got through the wall on their way home in [*Game of Thrones*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0944947/). Did Bran and Jojen do the same with a passage?

Answer (score 13):

> Did Bran and Jojen do the same with a passage?

Yes, the same passage, and Samwell and Gilly actually meet Brann, Jojen, Meera and Hodor in the The Nightfort after the former have just come through the sally port, in [S03E10- Mhysa](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2178796/):

[image: Samwell, Jojen, Hodor, Brann and Meera]

They're never really in the same shot together, but that's Sam's shoulder on the left of the frame. And the reverse perspective:

[image: Sam and Gilly]

Comment: And the implications of this would be...they went through the same passage?

Comment: Yeah, I'll make it clearer.

Comment: Correct. Bran and Jojen passed under the wall through the same passage at the Nightfort that sam and gilly used. In the books that's where Coldhands leaves Sam and joins Bran to head back north.